# how can i cancel saving the form's records automatically in ms-access 2010 macro

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

i designed a form in ms-access 2010 . it's based on a table . i want that when the user enter data into the form and shift to the next or previous record the last record he had been in, by default changes to read-only property to prevent the user from editing any data by mistake 
i hope the answer be by ms-access 2010 ***macro***

**second question** :
actually , i googled my question before asking but i failed the real reason
 when i designed a program in  ms-access-vba to be used across multiple pcs , i face a big problem

the problem that the code does not work at all on some pcs unless i setup a  version of windows 7 on the pc that the code doesnot work . and this solution is annoying and impractical
i hope to solve this annoying problem 
that's why i ask every time from you all that answers be by macro not by vba .although i love vba but macro proved to be the alternative soultion to this problem 
what shall i do? 
any ideas for that problem
thank you very much in advance

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not easy to understand. Do you want users to be able to **add** new records, but not **edit** existing records?

Comment: Yes ..thats exactly what i mean keep authority for users  to add new but prevent them from editing the existing records  unless  clicking on "Edit" Button on the loaded form  ...there is a lot of videos explain that but  by vba access ..while  my request is by macro ..how to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a property you should check `Form.DataEntry` allows you to enable the form to ONLY add new records, but not editing.

> **[Form.DataEntry property (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.dataentry)**

Play with VBA, make the form as only to add records, and then allow users to edit records **only if they click in the button to edit.** That way you can prevent mistakes as you wish.

I do now know how your database is designed and how your forms are designed/linked, but what I do is loading the same form in 1 mode or another (adding or editing), depending where the user clicks. That way, for me, is easier to control mistakes.

Comment: Thank ylu very much for all your valuable answers

Comment: I haI changed the property of all controls on the form to the property "locked" in the event of loading form and saving data . Unlike this way , un the event of "click " on Edit Button made the vice versa i.e unlocked the controls with the edit or cancel buttons